# How to control page routes in the controller?

Tags: onsen-ui

OnsenUI is great.  Fast and easy.  However, there is not much documentation for controlling Onsen logic in the controller.

Like for instance, I want to do a $location.path('/newpath') inside a controller. How is done in Onsen?  I tried "ons.navigator.pushPage('partials/latestjob.html');" in my controller function but doesn't work.  Are we limited to ng-click in Onsen to go to another page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Onsen UI 1.04, you can access navigator from inside the controller as follows.

```
$rootScope.ons.navigator.pushPage('new_page.html');
```

Another way is

```
$rootScope.ons.$get('#navigator').pushPage(pagename);
```

where `#navigator` is the `id` of navigator you put on s.t.

```
<ons-navigator id="navigator" page="page1.html"></ons-navigator>
```

This method can choose which navigator you use.

The third way is the one obtaining the navigator scope. For example,

```
var element = document.querySelector( ".navigator-container");
var scope = angular.element( element ).scope();
scope.pushPage(pagename);
```

The class name `.navigator-container` is a built-in class name of onsen ui navigator.
This goes well even in onsen ui 1.0.

adding: example of `$rootScope`

```
myapp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.pushPage = function(pagename) {
    $rootScope.ons.navigator.pushPage(pagename);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @KNaito.  I actually tried the first method just because it seems logical to do so but I got error particularly with $rootscope.  What do I need to declare or inject in the controller as dependencies?

Comment: I can not run the sample. Does anyone know why I'm getting this error: Cannot read property '$$phase' of null.

Comment: hai  @KNaito. do you have an answer for this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513659/onsen-uicontroll-android-backbutton-routes