# Onsen uI:Controll android backbutton routes:

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I am developing an android application in cordova using Onsenui,in which i want to navigate to previous page when device backbutton is clicked
I am using answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041536/how-to-control-android-backbutton-routes)  question to solve the issue

Here is my code

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton",onBackButtonPressed, false);
    function onBackButtonPressed(){
            alert('backbutton');
            var element = document.querySelector( ".navigator-container");
            var scope = angular.element( element ).scope();
            scope.popPage();
    }
```

I will get the following error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'popPage' of undefined"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably `.navigator-container` has been deprecated, that's why I suggest you to get the navigator by using `ons-navigator` as argument for `document.querySelector()`.

Here is the fixed code:

```js
document.addEventListener("backbutton",onBackButtonPressed, false);
    function onBackButtonPressed(){
            alert('backbutton');
            var element = document.querySelector("ons-navigator");
            element.popPage();
}
```

**EDIT**

Supposing that you are using an older version of Onsen UI, like 1.3.4, and supposing that your navigator has a `var='myNavigator'` attribute, you can use the following code:

```js
document.addEventListener("backbutton",onBackButtonPressed, false);
    function onBackButtonPressed(){
            alert('backbutton');
            var element = document.querySelector("ons-navigator");
            var scope = angular.element(element).scope();
            scope.myNavigator.popPage();
}
```

Comment: I will get another error element. `element.popPage is not a function`

Comment: Which version of Onsen UI are you using? With Onsen 1.3.11 it works fine. If you use an older version, try to execute `ons.compile(element);` before `element.popPage()`

Comment: back button works in home page only ,when click on sliding menu items app is exiting

Comment: I wll get  the following errors `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null`  ` "Uncaught Error: Fail to fire "pageinit" event. Attach "ons-page" element to the document after initialization`

Comment: My onsen ui version is v1.3.4

Comment: @shammon I just updated my answer with the solution for Onsen 1.3.4. If it's useful, please consider to upvote the question and mark it as best answer :) Anyway, I suggest you to update to Onsen 1.3.11

Comment: Let me try your answer

Comment: it works partially sometime i will get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'myNavigator' of undefined"

Comment: That's probably because you are trying to get the navigator in a page where the navigator doesn't exist. Or it happens always in the same page?

Comment: Nop it happens in another pages.

Comment: that's exactly what I thought, that's because you are trying to get the scope of the first page in another page, which is not possible. That's why it would be better for you to update you Onsen UI version.

Comment: for to latest version?

Comment: actually, you can put `var element = document.querySelector("ons-navigator");` outside the `eventListener` so it will be referenced always with the same navigator and will not try to retrieve the navigator every time it will be triggered

Comment: Now nothing is worked:(  this is the error  `You can not supply no "ons-page" element to "ons-navigator".`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94157/discussion-between-shammon-and-andi-pavllo).

Comment: That's another error and it's not related with this. Please try to modify your code as I suggested in the last comment, without changing the Onsen version